# Redirect a typeform page and show results on new page

Tags: wordpress, typeform

I have a typeform form that has a different score per answer. At the end of the form I want to redirect to a page on my website (on Wordpress). On that page I want to have a section that has the form results (eg "you scored 5 out of 10").

Is there a way to carry these results onto my website?

I've tried researching web hooks, but I am lost.

Answer (score 0):

I think this rather a Typeform question than a pure programmatic question.

On your Typeform you can create as many `Thank you` screen as you like.
Each `thank you` screen could have its own text and its own redirect link.

On the redirect link, you can pass a query parameter taking the value of the score calculated on Typeform. Click on the + button to select either a response to a question, a hidden field, or the calculated score.

And you can redirect the user to your Wordpress with a URL like
`https://mywebsite.com?score={value from typeform}`

If you have more questions you should contact Typeform support directly.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas.

I did reach out to them and they said its possible with some custom code, but can not give any advice on how to do that, or what direction to head in.

I know I can redirect to a URL with a hidden field added (like your example). I'm just lost on how I can actually display that text on the page.

Comment: It makes sense because this is outside of Typeform scope.
On Wordpress you need a piece of code that will extract values from the query string.
I think this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript